# Ошибка при подключении к DataBase

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, winforms

Пишу программу-тест для учеников. Для проверки подключения к БД Mysql сделал кнопку, которая оповещала о стабильном подключении. На моем ПК работает всё исправно, но при переносе программы на другой ПК выдаёт ошибку Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts (как я понимаю из-за отдаленности от сервера). Как же можно исправить данную ошибку без потери базы данных?

[image: нормальное подключение на основном ПК]

[image: ошибка при подключении на другом ПК]

Comment: MySQL - это сервер, который либо должен быть установлен у клиента, либо у вас, тогда в подключении должен указываться ваш открытый, публичный IP адрес (если одна сеть, то локальный, вашей сети). Также сам MySQL должен быть настроен на доступ из вне. Поэтому, перенести просто программу на другой компьютер, с использованием сервера, не получится.

Comment: Было бы неплохо глянуть на connection string для подключения к БД. Вполне вероятно, что там адрес сервера `localhost` необходимо заменить на актуальный IP вашего компьютера (при условии, что компьютеры учеников будут находиться в той же подсети).

Comment: Это сисадминский вопрос, уровень абстракции которого не позволяет мне, как сисадмину, дать конкретный ответ. Вы должны находиться либо в одной сети с базой, либо иметь маршрут до неё. TCP/IP.

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, настройки подключения (логин, пароль можно скрыть)

Comment: Сервер баз данных должен быть доступен для подключения. Это значит, что должен быть открыт порт для подключения и должна быть настроена соответствующая учетная запись в СУРБД MySQL.

Comment: Сначала проверьте, что сервер доступен по IP - через телнет проверьте просто факт подключения. Доступно? пробуйте подключение через CLI. Доступно? проверяйте авторизацию.